# Creating zip of android project along with its dependencies through gradle

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an android project which have three different dependencies (library projects) and I want to create a zip of each project src folder after we are finished with the builds. I did the following,

```
task srcZip(type: Zip) {
    from projectDir
    println "SOURCE THE ZIP"
    exclude 'build'
    exclude 'gen'
    exclude 'bin'
}
```

In order to make a zip however I have to call this task manually. This works only if I have to create a zip file of one project which does not include the sources of other dependencies (library projects). How can I create a zip of all the sources at once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have already created the source zip of other 2/N projects and it's available in Artifactory/Nexus or similar binary repo tool, then it's just a matter of using those artifacts (zips) and unpacking it to your workspace (ant.unzip can help within gradle or use Gradle code to unzip) and then once you have your current project checked out, from projectDir will take care of current project and you can point from otherproject1 and from otherproject2 (where otherprojectN is the location where you unpacked those 2 project's source) This assumes you first zip the source code of those projects

Comment: @ArunSangal - Thanks for the reply. But I need to zip the source, not unzip it. 2/N projects are not zipped. I am able to zip just the main project but not the other dependent library project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix the problem on my own,

Copying the following to all the dependent projects,

```
task srcZip(type: Zip) {
    from projectDir
    println "SOURCE THE ZIP"
    exclude 'build'
    exclude 'gen'
    exclude 'bin'
}
```