# Creating a zip of all app sources, excluding build files

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

To create a zip file of an Android project, the following task helps

```
task zip(type: Zip) {
    from '.'
    archiveName 'zip.zip'
    dependsOn 'clean'
    destinationDir = file('..')
}
```

It works fine, but does not always call the `clean` task, so that the `build` directory is sometimes included in the zip file. While [Creating zip of android project along with its dependencies through gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303863/creating-zip-of-android-project-along-with-its-dependencies-through-gradle) might be a workaround, it would be nice to know:

Why is the `clean` task not always triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Zip` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html) has an `excludes` parameter:

```
task zip(type: Zip) {
    from '.'
    archiveName 'submission.zip'
    destinationDir = file('..')
    excludes = ['**/gradle.properties', '**/build/**', '**/gen/**', '**/.idea/**', '**/.gradle/**', '**/other_dir_name/**']
}
```

Added benefit: the files are not deleted and recreated every time.